# Firebug for ie in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wine, internet-explorer-6, firebug

How to install firebug for ie6 which is installed in **ubuntu** platform using *wine*.

Comment: How does this classify as a programming question?

Comment: i think <script> tag not programming related according to ur dictionary

Answer (score 6):

If you mean [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), than there is no need to install anything in IE, but you have to add a script tag to the site you want to debug or use a [Javascript bookmarklet](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) that does this dynamically.

If you want the real Firebug it can't be done since Firebug is an extension for Firefox only.

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer does not support Firebug. Firebug can only be used in Mozilla Firefox, not any other browser.

Comment: Not entirely true. Firebug Lite is available for many browsers that supports Javascript.

Comment: firebug lite is something entirely different from firebug, and isn't 'installed' onto a browser...